# Saving custom columns to Devise enabled model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I created a Tenants model/controller/views for my application prior to bringing in Devise. Now, I've added Devise on to the existing model.

When registering a new Tenant, I want to add a number of new columns such as `:first_name` (and a few others). I've followed the documentation on the Devise github but, for some reason, I have no idea why the parameters that I add in are not getting saved to the database.

Here is my Application Controller that I've configured the way that the Devise documentation recommends (I am using Devise 3.2.4 and Rails 4.1.0). Please note that for now, I am just trying to save the `:first_name` to see if I can get any of the new parameters I am adding in to work:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name
  end

end
```

I also tried this method in my Application Controller (again, just using `:first_name` for now...I know my view has a number of additional parameters as well that I'll add once I can get `first_name` to work), which also didn't work:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :email) }
end
```

Here is my `new.html.erb`file:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rent_portion %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :rent_portion%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pays_tv %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :pays_tv %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sec_dep %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :sec_dep %>
  </div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Here is my Tenants controller (that I created prior to putting Devise on the model):

```
class TenantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tenant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 # after_action :determine_bill, only: [:summary]



  def index
    @tenants = Tenant.all
  end



  def new
    @tenant = Tenant.new
  end

  def edit

  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    @tenant.update(tenant_params)
      redirect_to tenants_path
  end

  def destroy
    @tenant.destroy
    redirect_to tenants_path

  end

  def create
    @tenant = Tenant.create(tenant_params)

    if @tenant.save
      redirect_to tenants_path, notice: 'Tenant was successfully created.' 

    else
    end
  end

  def summary
    @tenants = Tenant.all
    @bill = Bill.last
    @bills = Bill.all
  end

  def security_deposit
    @tenants = Tenant.all
    @bill = Bill.last
  end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.


    def set_tenant
      @tenant = Tenant.find(params[:id])
    end


    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def tenant_params
      params.require(:tenant).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :rent_portion, :pays_tv, :sec_dep)
    end


end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable



end
```

Using the methods above, when I look at what is saved in the database, only the original Devise parameters actually have values and everything else is nil. Why is this?

Comment: Which Rails version?

Comment: Rails 4.1.0 so yes, it needs the strong params...I have tried this but it hasn't worked

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like a Strong Parameters issue.

Rails 4 uses [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) which provides an interface for protecting attributes from end-user assignment. So, you need to let Devise know that you want to permit this new parameter:

Change this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name
end
```

For this:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
  u.permit(:first_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Basically, you want to pass any parameters that should be permitted as arguments to the `.permit` method.

Comment: Thanks! I did actually try that as well since that allows you to pass in a number of parameters that you want to whitelist with the strong params - however, I am still getting the same issue where only the Devise parameters (e.g., :email, encrypted_password, etc.) are saved...not my custom ones such as :first_name

Comment: Could you confirm that the parameters even reach the controller? Inspect tenan_params before doing the create

Comment: Ok is that done by incorporating <%= params.inspect %> into my view? If so, I get {"controller"=>"tenants", "action"=>"index"} in my view. Could this be that when I hit the form, because the submit button at sign up that some of the parameters aren't being routed to the devise create action in the controller?

Comment: In your create action of the controller, right before you do ``@tenant = Tenant.create(tenant_params)``, do ``p tenant_params``, and see if those fields are there. If not, they are not passed in the form.